# Execute curl command within a Python script

Tags: python, curl, pycurl

I am trying to execute a curl command within a python script.

If I do it in the terminal, it looks like this:

```
curl -X POST -d  '{"nw_src": "10.0.0.1/32", "nw_dst": "10.0.0.2/32", "nw_proto": "ICMP", "actions": "ALLOW", "priority": "10"}' http://localhost:8080/firewall/rules/0000000000000001
```

I've seen recommendations to use `pycurl`, but I couldn't figure out how to apply it to mine.

I tried using:

```
subprocess.call([
    'curl',
    '-X',
    'POST',
    '-d',
    flow_x,
    'http://localhost:8080/firewall/rules/0000000000000001'
])
```

and it works, but is there a better way?

Comment: You don't have to use `cURL` to POST something to a server.  `requests` can do so quite easily (as can `urllib`, with a bit more effort)

Comment: Check this to know more about executing shell cmds in python http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python

Answer (score 270, accepted):

## Don't!

I know, that's the "answer" nobody wants. But if something's worth doing, *it's worth doing right*, right?

This seeming like a good idea probably stems from a fairly wide misconception that shell commands such as `curl` are anything other than programs themselves.

So what you're asking is "how do I run this other program, from within my program, just to make a measly little web request?". That's crazy, there's got to be a better way right?

[Uxio's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26000778/1446048) works, sure. But it hardly looks very *Pythonic*, does it? That's a lot of work just for one little request. Python's supposed to be about [flying](https://xkcd.com/353/)! Anyone writing that is probably wishing they just `call`'d `curl`!

---

> it works, but is there a better way?

## Yes, there *is* a better way!

#### [Requests: HTTP for Humans](http://requests.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)

> Things shouldn’t be this way. Not in Python.

Let's GET this page:

```
import requests
res = requests.get('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26000336')
```

That's it, really! You then have the raw `res.text`, or `res.json()` output, the `res.headers`, etc.

You can see the docs (linked above) for details of setting all the options, since I imagine OP has moved on by now, and you - the reader now - likely need different ones.

But, for example, it's as simple as:

```
url     = 'http://example.tld'
payload = { 'key' : 'val' }
headers = {}
res = requests.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers)
```

You can even use a nice Python dict to supply the query string in a GET request with `params={}`.

Simple and elegant. Keep calm, and fly on.

Comment: I am using python 2.4.3. can't use requests. ImportError: No module named requests.

Comment: @Gary `pip install requests`

Comment: I had to do json.dumps(payload), but didn't need to use the json.dumps method on headers.

Comment: Right @user1045085, because you wanted to send a JSON payload - but `headers` is a (dictionary, not string) argument to a Python function, so JSON doesn't come into it.

Comment: @OllieFord Do you know by any chance if this would this work for Firebase? Im new to Fb and python but they have a REST API which they have documented as accepting curl requests.

Comment: @marciokoko Most definitely! :) `requests` is "just" HTTP under the hood. Use it as you would curl, but fly faster with Python.

Comment: +1.  To the best of my knowledge, anything that can be done with cURL can also be done via python requests.  Might as well use that one instead.

Comment: this worked perfectly for what I came looking for. Thanks @OJFord

Comment: Doesn't work on kibana due to content security policy issues.

Comment: @I'll Eat My Hat - refer to Kibana API docs. If that's the case, it's true of using curl directly too, not a problem introduced by `requests`.

Comment: It turns out that kibana just returns very bad error messages.

Comment: How to insert option then?  There are quite a number of option when using curl

Comment: @LukAron See the docs here: http://requests.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ For converting an existing curl command with several options, it might be easier to use a tool that can convert for you, like Postman app or in the browser at https://curl.trillworks.com/

Comment: I found this blog helpful and echos OJFord's answer in additional detail: https://www.nylas.com/blog/use-python-requests-module-rest-apis/

Comment: sometimes it is just easier when dealing with proxies, kerberos and  other firewall related stuff that you don't want to install 20 packeages for python in addition to get it working...that's why I can relate to the question

Comment: As great as Requests is, I landed here due to a (TLS?) bug that has been fixed in curl but not yet in urllib3 leveraged by Requests, causing timeouts during the TLS handshake.

Comment: @idungotnosn Here might be something: Can `requests` send emails via SMTP as easily as curl? https://www.baeldung.com/linux/curl-send-mail

Comment: @Ferd No, `requests` supports only HTTP(S) by design.

Answer (score 67):

Use this [tool](https://github.com/NickCarneiro/curlconverter) (hosted [here](https://curlconverter.com/) for free) to convert your curl command to equivalent Python requests code:

Example: This,

```
curl 'https://www.example.com/' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'Cache-Control: max-age=0' -H 'Origin: https://www.example.com' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br' -H 'Cookie: SESSID=ABCDEF' --data-binary 'Pathfinder' --compressed
```

Gets converted neatly to:

```
import requests

cookies = {
    'SESSID': 'ABCDEF',
}

headers = {
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
    'Origin': 'https://www.example.com',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
}

data = 'Pathfinder'

response = requests.post('https://www.example.com/', headers=headers, cookies=cookies, data=data)
```

Comment: While @OJFord has enlightened us why not to use curl within python, Nitin has depicted the simplest way to implement the same using "requests". I highly recommend this answer.

Answer (score 46):

You could use urllib as @roippi said:

```
import urllib2
data = '{"nw_src": "10.0.0.1/32", "nw_dst": "10.0.0.2/32", "nw_proto": "ICMP", "actions": "ALLOW", "priority": "10"}'
url = 'http://localhost:8080/firewall/rules/0000000000000001'
req = urllib2.Request(url, data, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
f = urllib2.urlopen(req)
for x in f:
    print(x)
f.close()
```

Comment: is urllib2 more time efficient compared to subprocess?

Comment: It depends of the subprocess, but spawing subprocesses calling commands when the language has core libraries to do so it's not definitely the right way to do it

Comment: TypeError: POST data should be bytes, an iterable of bytes, or a file object. It cannot be of type str.

Answer (score 39):

If you are not tweaking the curl command too much you can also go and call the curl command directly

```
import shlex
cmd = '''curl -X POST -d  '{"nw_src": "10.0.0.1/32", "nw_dst": "10.0.0.2/32", "nw_proto": "ICMP", "actions": "ALLOW", "priority": "10"}' http://localhost:8080/firewall/rules/0000000000000001'''
args = shlex.split(cmd)
process = subprocess.Popen(args, shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout, stderr = process.communicate()
```

Comment: Thanks,

I implemented it using subprocess.call()

Comment: I was very well helped with the suggestion of @Ollie Ford: I have installed Requests under W10. From command line, started up Python and then composed my requested URL. From now I'll have to figure out how to set up (and view the contents of) a stream in a .py file. Suggestions welcome!

Comment: "subprocess" is not defined

Answer (score 14):

Try with subprocess

```
CurlUrl="curl 'https://www.example.com/' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'Cache- 
          Control: max-age=0' -H 'Origin: https://www.example.com' -H 'Accept-Encoding: 
          gzip, deflate, br' -H 'Cookie: SESSID=ABCDEF' --data-binary 'Pathfinder' -- 
          compressed"
```

Use `getstatusoutput` to store the results

```
status, output = subprocess.getstatusoutput(CurlUrl)
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use below code snippet

```
import shlex
import subprocess
import json

def call_curl(curl):
    args = shlex.split(curl)
    process = subprocess.Popen(args, shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    stdout, stderr = process.communicate()
    return json.loads(stdout.decode('utf-8'))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    curl = '''curl - X
    POST - d
    '{"nw_src": "10.0.0.1/32", "nw_dst": "10.0.0.2/32", "nw_proto": "ICMP", "actions": "ALLOW", "priority": "10"}'
    http: // localhost: 8080 / firewall / rules / 0000000000000001 '''
    output = call_curl(curl)
    print(output)
```

Answer (score 3):

Rephrasing one of the answers in this post, instead of using cmd.split(). Try to use:

```
import shlex

args = shlex.split(cmd)
```

Then feed args to subprocess.Popen.

Check this doc for more info: https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor

Answer (score 1):

Inside the `subprocess` module, there is one more option called `run` use it

```
from subprocess import run
run(curl -X POST -d  '{"nw_src": "10.0.0.1/32", "nw_dst": "10.0.0.2/32", "nw_proto": "ICMP", "actions": "ALLOW", "priority": "10"}' http://localhost:8080/firewall/rules/0000000000000001)
```

Answer (score 0):

With Python 3, the built-in [HTTP protocol client](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html) is a viable alternative to cURL. Using the example provided:

```
>>> import http.client, urllib.parse
>>> params = urllib.parse.urlencode({"nw_src": "10.0.0.1/32", "nw_dst": "10.0.0.2/32", "nw_proto": "ICMP", "actions": "ALLOW", "priority": "10"})
>>> headers = {"Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "Accept": "text/plain"}
>>> conn = http.client.HTTPConnection("localhost:8080")
>>> conn.request("POST", "/firewall/rules/0000000000000001", params, headers)
>>> response = conn.getresponse()
>>> print(response.status, response.reason)
302 Found
>>> data = response.read()
>>> conn.close()
```