# curl -u equivalent in python

Tags: python, authentication, curl

I'm trying to download a file from a website which requires log-in.
By command line it can easily be done via

```
curl --proxy-anyauth -p -c cookie -u user:psw -L url > file.ext
```

Any advices on how to do that in python?
Thank you

Comment: maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26000336/how-to-execute-a-curl-command-within-a-python-script can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never used this before however I think this could work.
Here is the link to PyCurl library

http://pycurl.sourceforge.net

Comment: https://www.google.co.uk/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=python+curl&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=kYvkVJKlN4zCWK6UgNAN . Wonders what a simple google search does!

Comment: Thanks,
I tried PyCurl, but in the end i choose to use requests.
requests.get(url, auth=(user, pWord)) seems a far clearer way to me.

Comment: Ok. Glad you found something you liled