# How pass option of curl in request in python?

Tags: python, api, curl, github, request

As the answer and comment in   https://stackoverflow.com/a/31764155/10189759
suggest that everything could be done using a curl could be done using python request.

My question is how to pass option like -u -i to the request  function?

For example in this tutorial [github api](https://developer.github.com/v3/guides/getting-started/)

`curl -i -u your_username:your_token https://api.github.com/user`

How could I use request to pass my args and option to the url?

Comment: Do you know what those commands do? Have you read the requests docs?

Comment: I've posted below, but please in the future add code samples which show what have you tried so far, and as @jonrsharpe suggested read requests docs.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
import requests

response = requests.get('https://api.github.com/user', auth=('your_username', 'your_token'))
```