# Curl is generating status 400 in subprocess

Tags: python, python-3.x, curl, subprocess

I run a curl command on windows command line prompt. It produces a `json` output. The command looks like this:

```
curl --data "action=details&user=user&project=project1&problemid=2021" https://website:9020/
```

I issue the same command in python as following:

```
import subprocess
output = subprocess.run(
                [
                    "curl",
                    "--data",
                    "\"action=details&user=user&project=project1&problemid=2021\""
                    "https://website:9020/",
                ],
                stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
                shell=True,
            )
print(output.stdout.decode("utf-8"))
```

The output is the following:

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   199  100    64  100   123     64    123  0:00:01 --:--:--  0:00:01  1254
{"status":400,"message":"Action parameter is missing"}
```

But the command line produces a json output. Yet the same command issued through `subprocess.run` produces this error. I also tried it with `subprocess.Popen` and `subprocess.check_output`. Same issue persists. What am I doing wrong here that is causing this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In some cases (e.g. if they require running command line as administrator), `subprocess` might not be the right choice to execute the command line commands.

You can use `os.system()` to see the output or `os.popen()` to read and store the output.

```
import os
import json

# to see the output 
print(os.system("curl --data \"action=details&user=user&project=project1&problemid=2021\" https://website:9020/")

output = os.popen("curl --data \"action=details&user=user&project=project1&problemid=2021\" https://website:9020/").read()

outputjson = json.loads(output)
```

then you can access the `json` information.

Comment: You'll notice that the `os.system` documentation recommends that you use `subprocess` instead,  and that `os.popen` is just a thin and basically redundant wrapper around `subprocess`.

Comment: But it did not work for me. `os.popen` did.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try running your code without the quotation marks around the action parameter? Because the API is complaining about missing action parameter. I think it's just not recognising it due to the escaped quotation marks.

```
import subprocess
output = subprocess.run(
    [
        "curl",
        "--data",
        "action=details&user=user&project=project1&problemid=2021"
        "https://website:9020/",
    ],
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
    shell=True,
)
print(output.stdout.decode("utf-8"))
```

EDIT: I'm not sure if this is the case, but it could be that subprocess implicitly surrounds all its parameters with quotation marks in order to avoid code injection and globbing.

I was just googling again and found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31764155/6180150), which states it quite well: why would you use curl, if you could use requests?

No guarantee, but I think something like this should work:

```
import requests
url = "https://website:9020/"
payload = {
    "action": "details",
    "user": "user",
    "project": "project1",
    "problemid": "2021"
}
res = requests.get(url, params=payload)
```

Comment: No, it's the opposite. When you run the command in the shell, you need to quote the data to protect it from modification by the shell; but here you have no shell, and so the quotes are not only unnecessary, but wrong.

Comment: Yeah, it does not work without the quotation marks. If I run without them, it says "action" is not recognized as internal command. Curl does not automatically wrap the parameters with quotation marks.

Comment: That's explained in more detail in [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable) but again, this answer is correct, just not the speculation in the edit. I guess "implicitly" makes it kind of right, but not really.

Comment: Wait, the `shell=True` is horribly wrong here.

Comment: @tripleee should it be false? or that option should not exist at all? I tried with both but error persists.

Comment: Omitting it defaults to `False` so both are fine, but usually just leave it out.

Comment: I printed `output` it gave me this: `CompletedProcess(args=['curl', '--data', '"action=details&user=user&project=project1&problemid=2021"', 'https://website:9020/'], returncode=0, stdout=b'`

Comment: @VancePyton Did you check my latest edit of the answer? Try using the requests package instead of calling curl with subprocess. That is the more pythonic and clean solution.