# How to run cURL request using python

Tags: python, curl

I would like to know how to run the following cURL request using python (I'm working in Jupyter notebook):

```
curl -i -X GET "https://graph.facebook.com/{graph-api-version}/oauth/access_token?  
grant_type=fb_exchange_token&          
client_id={app-id}&
client_secret={app-secret}&
fb_exchange_token={your-access-token}"
```

I've seen some similar questions and answers suggesting using "requests.get", but I am a complete python newbie and am not sure how to structure the syntax for whole request including the id, secret and token elements. Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Execute curl command within a Python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26000336/execute-curl-command-within-a-python-script)

Comment: You can use pycurl

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26000336/execute-curl-command-within-a-python-script/66242608#66242608 Checkout this question as I find it duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

no need to use curl. use the below

```
import requests

graph_api_version = 'a'
app_id = 'b'
app_secret = 'c'
your_access_token = 'd'
url = f"https://graph.facebook.com/{graph_api_version}/oauth/access_token?grant_type=fb_exchange_token&client_id={app_id}&client_secret={app_secret}&fb_exchange_token={your_access_token}"
r = requests.get(url)
```

Comment: @David23C Did you replace a,b,c,d with the real values?

Comment: Thanks - the app_id had a typo - seems to be working now

Answer (score 0):

you can use some lib that run commands in python like `subprocess`. for example: `subprocess.run(["curl", "google.com"])`

Comment: I think the OP is looking for a Python cURL library like there is in PHP.

Comment: I think there is no such thing!

Comment: There is pycurl.io

Comment: This is what I've seen in a related post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26000336/execute-curl-command-within-a-python-script), but I am still not sure how to rewrite my code above using 'subprocess'. Are you able to show how the final code should look? I have the app_id, secret & access token.

Answer (score 0):

Convert your Curl request to Python instantly here :
https://curl.trillworks.com/